# Are there somebodies use OpenCV2.2 with ROS?

Tags: ros, vision-opencv, cv-bridge, opencv2.2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to translate my previous code by opencv2.2 into ROS, and I have found many differences between opencv and ROS in image type and some other types. So I wander if some one have already developed  a long time on it, please give me some advices?

Thanks a lot!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9169/are-there-somebodies-use-opencv2.2-with-ros-?/) by [Yongqiang Gao](https://answers.ros.org/users/162/yongqiang-gao/) on ROS Answers with karma: 133 on 2011-02-22

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

ROS default install uses OpenCV 2.0
You can upgrade to 2.2 if you replace the ROS opencv2 package with the one available her:
http://www.ros.org/wiki/vision_opencv
just do svn co https://code.ros.org/svn/ros-pkg/stacks/vision_opencv/trunk
and make it.

---

Originally posted by [Yogi](https://answers.ros.org/users/105/yogi/) with karma: 411 on 2011-02-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) on 2011-02-23**:
Just a note -- cturtle used OpenCV 2.0, diamondback/unstable are using 2.2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I suggest you take a look at the documentation for the [vision_opencv](http://www.ros.org/wiki/vision_opencv) stack. Diamondback will include OpenCV 2.2, so that shouldn't be a problem for you.

As far as the differences between OpenCV and ROS image types, the [cv_bridge](http://www.ros.org/wiki/cv_bridge) addresses these concerns. Make sure to read the tutorials linked to from the cv_bridge package documentation to learn how to convert ROS images to OpenCV images and vice versa. Because Cturtle and Diamondback have different cv_bridge APIs, you should make sure you have the proper version selected when viewing the tutorials.

---

Originally posted by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) with karma: 8406 on 2011-02-22

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3